# Eclipse showing "Maven Configuration Problem: Unknown"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I just imported a spingboot project that I created in https://start.spring.io/ in eclipse.
I tried to import two times, but the problem persists.
Already tried to do a mvn update , a mvn clean install, tried to clean the project but none of this worked.
Its a problem in the first line of pom xml file.
I dont have any idea how to solve this.
I'm using java 11

[image: error]

This is the complete POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot.rest.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-2-jpa-with-hibernate-and-h2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-2-jpa-with-hibernate-and-h2</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Romulo-S/Manager-System

Comment: I ran into this same problem, it was [Bug 547340 - Cannot import any project into Eclipse with maven-jar-plugin 3.1.2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340).  SOLUTION: `Eclipse > Help > Install New Software >
          Work with= https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/signed/mavenarchiver/0.17.4/, <Enter>, 
          m2e extensions= Y > Next...`  Updating m2e did *NOT* work.  Manually installing m2e 0.17.4 *DID* work.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This seems like a bug in eclipse:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340

You can fix this by temporary downgrading the maven jar plugin version to 3.1.1 from 3.1.2. Add this to the *properties* section:

```
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
```

So your pom will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot.rest.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-2-jpa-with-hibernate-and-h2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-2-jpa-with-hibernate-and-h2</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Update:**
A fix has been released. Click Help > Check for updates in Eclipse/STS and install the newest m2e connector.

Comment: Thanks!                                                                                                                           By the way, how did you find that this is a bug?

Comment: @RomuloSorato no problem ;) I also use eclipse, so I created a dummy project to reproduce the issue, after creation I immediatly encountered the issue. Tried maven build and application run, it worked flawlessly, so I concluded it could be a bug in eclipse. I did a search for 'maven' in the eclipse bugzilla and found an issue that seemed similiar

Comment: Thats nice! Thanks again.

Comment: No luck with the 'update' to m2e, running latest downloadable eclipse, with the m2e milestone 1.12.0.20190529-1915, and it still does't work

Comment: Ah, it's the m2e-wtp, updating from this milestones download site made it work http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/milestones/1.4. You might want to add that in big letters :)

Answer (score 14):

**Step 1:**

Downgrade to `<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>`

```
<properties>
    <java.version>X</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

**Step 2** *Update Project*

- Right Click on your Project
- Go to Maven
- Click on Update Project
- Clean and Re-Run your Application

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The application runs fine,however, the error in line 1 persists

Comment: Do *NOT* downgrade anything.  Eclipse "update" didn't help me, either. Instead, manually install the fix for Eclipse Bug 547340: `Eclipse > Help > Install New Software > Work with= https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/signed/mavenarchiver/0.17.4/, <Enter>, m2e extensions= Y > Next...`

Answer (score 7):

```
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
```

Add this dependency in pom.xml under properties tag

Answer (score 4):

For spring boot project I have added this:

```
<properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        </properties>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25753230)

Answer (score 2):

Was Getting exact same error.  Solution by Gybandi kinda worked for me.

- Updating project in Maven> menu does nothing to make error icon go away.
- Did the 3.1.1 and then did a maven -> update project from context menu. **The red (x) icon is now GONE** :-).  But I really don't want to downgrade my maven plugin, if possible.
- The suggestion of updating m2e-connector from eclipse marketplace
  does not work.  All I see against the m2e-connector entry is a "learn
  more" link which takes me to its webpage.  Nothing like
  "upgrade/update" button present.

Comment: you could also try Help > Install new software, select "All Available sites" from "Work with" combobox and type in m2e in search, then check in the  "m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties" under m2e extensions

Comment: @gybandi thanks! Sadly I have the same problem as G.A.. Of course downgrading to v3.1.1 worked, but I would like not to have to do that. Now when I try to check for updates, it says there are none. Trying to get it from the Eclipse Market does not get me further either. I am using Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200. I'll give Eclipse 2019-06 RC1 since I have some time on my hands.

Comment: @Igor have you tried "Install new software" section instead of the Eclipse Marketplace/Check for updates? Sometimes marketplace does not work for me neither

Comment: @gybandi I actually did not try the Marketplace - just "Install New Software" from the Help-menu... weird... No proxy (since it was from my home PC) either...

Answer (score 2):

if you are using spring boot downgrade the version to `2.1.4.RELEASE` instead of `2.1.5.RELEASE` it will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I am using eclipse photon and had similar issue. Didnt want to add the maven-jar-plugin.version in my pom as I dont want my codebase to contain code specific to IDE.

What I noticed is eclipse photon has m2e version of 1.5 which is causing the problem. I uninstall all the m2e connectors, restarted  my eclipse and then installed the m2e connector using the below url manually

https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.13/

this worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Adding packaging tag solved my problem. Didn't need to lower maven-jar plugin version.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the version from 2.1.6 to 2.1.3

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I changed this to 2.1.3 because there were two versions were shown available in local m2 repository at below path

.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent