# How to solve Maven Configuration Problem with Android application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I opened Android app like maven project in Eclipse but here is Maven Configuration Problem - Unknown?
I read this post about springboot project [Eclipse showing "Maven Configuration Problem: Unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212981/eclipse-showing-maven-configuration-problem-unknown) but I don't understand so good. 
[image]

Entire pom.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>at.axtesys</groupId>
<artifactId>soljoy</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>soljoy</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>3.9.0-rc.1</android.plugin.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.loopj.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>19</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I used Android API 21 and Java 8.
Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Removed the codehaus repository cause it does not exist anymore (longer time)

Answer (score 1):

I was also puzzled with this problem until I found the solution here  [eclipse-showing-maven-configuration-problem-unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212981/eclipse-showing-maven-configuration-problem-unknown) (same URL you mentioned )

you need to add below in your pom.xml properties

```
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
```

like below snippet from my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Do I need download or include .jar file or just add one line in pom.xml file?

Comment: just add one line in pom file