# Spring Boot Dependency

Tags: spring, dependencies, pom.xml

Why this error occurs every time while I import a spring boot project?
[image: what kind of error that is?]

Answer (score 0):

It is due to missing of dependencies. 
Use `mvn clean install` from command line before importing project to eclipse.

Also, this question can help - [Eclipse showing "Maven Configuration Problem: Unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212981/eclipse-showing-maven-configuration-problem-unknown)